# Postgres and JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm converting postgres to Exasol, gonna run some time trials on supposedly a super-fast DB. Exasol has an import script which I'm using and getting a "Connection refused error". This is for a local connection, Windows 10 and postgres 9.4

Things I've double-checked:

- port is 5432 (visible from PGAdmin)
- postgres is active and listening on 5432 (got the PID and saw it
  running)
- username and password have been retyped a few times
- tried specifying both IPV4 and 6 addresses ("localhost", 127.0.0.1 and      [::1] )
- postgres is accepting TCP traffic ("pg_hba" has:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/128           md5

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

Here is the error msg:
[43000] "JDBC-Client-Error: Connecting to 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/tom_db' as user='postgres' failed  [Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.]"

Any ideas? Not sure what to check next...

Comment: Have you checked the Windows firewall? It might be blocking the connection.

Comment: Do you have Skype running on that machine? If so, try shutting it down and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I saw both of those mentioned as potential problems and didn't include them in the "things I tried" list. Skype was not running and I disabled the Firewall.

Answer (score -1):

are using the EXASOL community edition in a VM ?

If so, you don't want 127.0.0.1

For example I have my EXASOL database running as a VM on my laptop at 192.168.56.123 and I am running postgres directly on my laptop (which is 192.168.56.1 as well as 127.0.0.1)

In this case my JDBC connection would use 192.168.56.1 for connecting from EXASOL to postgres

Hope this helps  - bear in mind too that you can also post these questions on the EXASOL community website https://www.exasol.com/portal/questions

Comment: Yes Graham, community in a VM. I tried your suggestion but still not happening. (Also thanks for the link to their site)    I spoke with them this morning and will be having a techie call next week, at which time I'll update.